Could the genAI policy be made clear on which genAI use cases are allowed or not allowed?
I'm confused by which genAI use cases are allowed by the current genAI policy.  meta.stackexchange.com/help/gen-ai-policy states:

Generative artificial intelligence (a.k.a. GPT, LLM, generative AI, genAI) tools may not be used to generate content for Meta Stack Exchange. [...] “Content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools” is any content crafted, in part or in whole, using a tool that writes a response automatically based on a prompt it is provided.

However, it seems that some genAI use cases are allowed, e.g. grammar improvement and speech recognition.
Could the genAI policy be made clear on which genAI use cases are allowed, or conversely, which genAI use cases are not allowed?
Examples of genAI use cases (in random order) on any SE site: translation, summarization, paraphrasing, question title generation (based on question body), grammar improvement, spelling improvement, image captioning, other types of improvement such as splitting overly long sentences, speech recognition, table markdown formatting, improvement formatting, text-to-image, text tone change, text simplification (e.g., ELI5). And there are some genAI use cases more specific to some SE sites e.g. image-to-latex generation, code refactoring or automatic music transcription.

Probably easier to define what's not allowed (at least in terms of underlying principles) - there are more potential use-cases emerging all the time - easier to add to the "forbidden list" I'd have thought.

I haven't voted either way, but the downvotes could be because you keep rule lawyering the GenAI ban on SO to . . . let off some steam? I don't honestly know what you're trying to accomplish here. Thus, the downvoters might be thinking this question is not asked in good faith.

@M.A.R. thanks, that's just my 2nd question on it. Trying to avoid getting banned.

Downvotes on meta sites of Stack Exchange, this one included, usually mean "I don't agree". It may be it with the direct request, or as in your case, the gist of the discussion that you try again and again to challenge the AI ban.

@ShadowWizard Thanks, I am just trying the understand the ban.  Where do you see I challenge the AI ban here?

You also said more than once that you support GenAI content to be posted in SE, so it is just matter of 1+1.

@ShadowWizard Yes but here I didn't express any support GenAI content to be posted in SE.

@FranckDernoncourt while votes are not personal (or should not be), we are also humans and we have the context of the person who posted something. Once we get a general idea about specific person "agenda" this will "stick", for good and for bad. If you express your opinion once, it won't suddenly go away if you don't mention it in other post. Anyway, all this said - this is only to explain about downvotes, and I agree it's very tricky and sometimes not really fair, but that's how SE/Meta work.

you asked why you were downvoted. Shadow Wizard explained (both the expectations of votes, and also what is likely going on here). It's not an answer to that to say "but here I didn't do X" - it doesn't change Shadow Wizard's likely correct explanation.

@jen thanks, yes I got it, though note that Shadow Wizard explained too, votes aren't supposed to be personal (ie, targeting specific users).

@FranckDernoncourt: It's up to each site what use cases are disallowed, if any. Or are you asking just about Meta S.E?

@Scortchi Got to start with one, and I thought maybe someone understood the default wording of the genAI policy.

If you're still curious, I downvoted because: a) This seems like a [tag:feature-request] disguised as [tag:support], and b) It seems to be based on false premises (asking ChatGPT to fix grammar is generally frowned upon, and the top answer to the speech recognition question specifically identifies speech recognition as not being Gen AI).

@Anerdw Thanks, a) good point b) yes, about the top answer to the speech recognition,  it says "And in general it is important to interpret the ban in the spirit that it was intended, i.e., to prevent flooding the site with content of unknown quality which cannot be handled within the capacity of the human curation systems of the site. Speech recognition clearly does not fall into that category.", therefore I thought many of the used I listed, including typo/grammar fixing, would be allowed. That's partly why I asked that 2nd question.

(so basically the top answer here contradicts the top answer to the speech recognition question)

I wish we could go back to when I could simply decide for myself what to post; it worked fine for over a decade.  For now, it's best to self-censor.

I don't think it's about the tools, but rather the intention. Note the below is my own personal view only.
Some needed background
The purpose of the ban is to protect Stack Exchange users from possibly wrong answers.
Usually, wrong answer, when detected, should get downvotes and possibly comment explaining why it's wrong when not obvious, and in extreme cases, deleted.
However, in case of GenAI it becomes much more tricky, because answer written with it appears to be fine and correct, and some might be indeed correct, however there is a high risk of incorrect answers that are hard to detect as wrong. It would not be feasible and we (the community/reviewers) don't have enough resources to check every such answer, hence a blanket ban.

Now to the point. I'll use some examples:

ChatGPT: the most simple case, blanket ban - even partially, e.g. taking parts of the reply while adding your own. Of course it would be impossible to prove on some cases, but still - it will be against the policy.
Grammarly: this is less obvious, and depends how you're using it. If you write your own answer, then ask Grammarly to just fix typos this should be fine and not against the policy, as the content is yours and the AI did not change its meaning. However, you must be careful and make sure it did not change your answer. And asking the service to rewrite your answer to be e.g. in different "tone" is banned by the policy, as this would make it a GenAI content, not yours anymore.
Speech recognition: also depends how you're using it, and what for. If you're turning your own voice to text in order to reply, this is allowed, unless of course you give the tool orders to change it into something else. In case of transcript, if the question you're answering asks for a transcript of a voice recording, and you're using GenAI for this, such answer would indeed be banned as it is GenAI content, based on the recording which is the prompt. However, if the question is not asking for a transcript and the answer only mentions it, this is not banned.


Thanks! Regarding your example, by "ChatGPT", do you mean LLM? Also, regarding "If you write your own answer, then ask Grammarly to just fix typos this should be fine and not against the policy", what if one asks GPT the same? Is that banned or allowed then?

@FranckDernoncourt I can’t find a source for this but I think that’s not allowed on SO

@FranckDernoncourt yes, ChatGPT is just example. Any LLM that would generate text based on prompt is the same, for the ban purpose. As for fixing typos, it's not designed for this so it would most likely change the meaning even if you tell it otherwise. So that is not a way to avoid the blanket ban. The main issue is with "generate text" - I want to believe Grammarly are honest enough to leave only typo fixing tools, even AI powered, that really won't change meaning i.e. won't generate their own text, hence giving it the benefit of the doubt. Do note, others might disagree and ban even that.

@Franck as a general example for using ChatGPT for something it's not designed for, try playing chess with it. It starts fine, and can "last" perhaps 10 moves. But then it starts to make things up, make illegal moves, etc.

@ShadowWizard Hmm, so I just played a quick game of chess with ChatGPT. Never tried that before: White: 9. O-O White castles. Black: You have just castled again? ChatGPT said: "It looks like there was an error earlier in our game notation, and I apologize for the confusion. You’re right; castling twice is not possible. To ensure clarity, could you please provide the current position or remind me of your last valid move? Then, I can make sure we're on track for the game." Like you said, perhaps 10 moves.

@PeterJames Here’s what happens if you try to keep going https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWhlrkfJrCQ

@ShadowWizard "it would most likely change the meaning even if you tell it otherwise." is incorrect for any strong LLM (eg, GPT 4, as reported in this EMNLP 2023 paper).

@FranckDernoncourt I don't see how "Handle Unnatural Scrambled Text" is related to changing meaning of a sentence/paragraph.

@ShadowWizard Able to handle scrambled text = unlikely to change meaning of a sentence/paragraph See How good are LLMs to fix typos? for more studies. Add yours.

@Franck From the current top answer to the question you linked: "while GPT-4 has higher recall than other methods, LLMs tend to have lower precision, leading to overcorrection." "while GPT models are very effective at identifying errors, they tend to make more corrections than necessary, potentially altering the meaning or style of the text." "LLMs generate text based on patterns learned from training data ... resulting in the replacement of grammatically correct words with other words that may occur more frequently in a given context."

As to the unscrambling study - unscrambling is a much more deterministic and specific task than "please fix/improve the grammar/spelling in this sample." Also, the study focused on fairly short text samples, which don't seem like great fits for Stack Exchange's more long-form content.

@Anerdw yes but we're far from the claim "it would most likely change the meaning even if you tell it otherwise." and o1 is much stronger than gpt 4 so it'd be interesting to rerun the study with o1. idk if text length significantly impacts faithfulness.

@Franck "Mostly likely" isn't really the threshold here; as long as a GPT alters original intent somewhat often, I think it should still be banned. As to the "tell it otherwise" note - that first study specifically said "don't change the meaning of this passage" in the prompts. Also, "it would be interesting to rerun the study" seems a little irrelevant in a conversation about whether GPT should be allowed right now. And text length does impact faithfulness because they probability of at least one mistake occurring in a text increases as the text grows longer.

@Anerdw yes obviously, was thinking faithfulness per token.

@ShadowWizard "As for fixing typos, it's not designed for this " here are some LLMs designed for this: SmolRewriter; GPT's Predicted Outputs.
